# I want to point an element with specific property in some list

Tags: python

Let a be `[{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}]` and b be `(n,10)`.(`n` is arbitrary)

My purpose is to insert 10 to a.

To be specific, if `n` is an element of one of `{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}`, I want insert 10 to that element. For example, if n=2, the result should be `a=[{1,2,3,10},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}]`.

Of course it was easy to check the existence of such element, but I couldn't insert 10 to that elements. How can I point that element? Is there any way to point such an element?

I want to know the solution because I have encountered this situation in many cases...

```
a=[{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}]
b=[3,10]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if b[0] in a[i]:
        a[i]=a[i]|{b[1]}
        print(a[i])
print(a)
```

This is my code, but I believe that there are better ways.

Comment: are the sets inside `a`  all unique?

Comment: To add to a set use `add()`. Example: `next((x for x in a if b[0] in x), set()).add(b[1])`

Comment: Yes they are unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to retrieve position index and list element value at the same time.

```
a = [{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}]
b = (2, 10)
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if b[0] in x:
        a[i].add(b[1])
        break
print(a)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/jeq23w)

Comment: I suggest you to check the answer if you find it helpful or does directly answer your question.